# Avoid going to the top of web page when opening a modal

Tags: javascript, popup

When I press a button to open a pop-up window, we also go to the top of the web page at the same time. How can I change the code so that when we click the button we won't go to the top of the page?

```
const modal = document.getElementById("modal")
const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay")
const openBtn = document.getElementById("openBtn")
const closeBtn = document.getElementById("closeBtn")

openBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    modal.style.display = "block"
    overlay.style.display = "block"
})

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    modal.style.display = "none"
    overlay.style.display = "none"
})
```

Comment: try making it `position:absolute` or use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`.

Comment: You need to show the relevant HTML and CSS as well.